# Space in f-string leads to ValueError: Invalid format specifier

Tags: python, python-3.x, f-string

A colleague and I just stumbled across an interesting problem using an f-string. Here is a minimal example:

```py
>>> f"{ 42:x}"
'2a'
```

Writing a space after the hexadecimal type leads to a `ValueError`:

```py
>>> f"{ 42:x }"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: Invalid format specifier
```

I understand the paragraph [*Leading and trailing whitespace in expressions is ignored* in PEP 498](https://peps.python.org/pep-0498/#leading-and-trailing-whitespace-in-expressions-is-ignored) to mean that the space should actually be ignored.

Why does the space character lead to an error and what is the reasoning behind this?

Comment: The syntax is `{ <expression> <optional !s, !r, or !a> <optional : format specifier> }`, per PEP 498. `42` is the expression. `x` is a format specifier, and `:` a delimiter; they are not a part of the expression.

Comment: A space could actually be a meaningful part of a format specifier, so spaces cannot be ignored.

Comment: Thank you! I just looked into [PEP 3101](https://peps.python.org/pep-3101/#standard-format-specifiers) and " " is indeed a valid value for the "sign" option.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Per the link you shared:

> For ease of readability, leading and trailing whitespace in
> expressions is ignored. This is a by-product of enclosing the
> expression in parentheses before evaluation.

The expression is everything<sup>[1]</sup> before the colon (`:`), while the format specifier is everything afterwards.

`{ 42 : x }` inside an `f-string` is equivalent to `( 42 )` with a format specifier of `" x "`.

`( 42 ) == 42` but `" x " != "x"`, and a format specifier is passed to the object's [`__format__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__format__#object.__format__) intact.

When the object attempts to format, it doesn't recognize the meaning of space (`" "`) in those positions, and throws an error.

Furthermore, on some format specifiers, space actually has a meaning, for example as a [fill character](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#grammar-token-format-spec-fill) or as a [sign option](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#grammar-token-format-spec-sign):

```
>>> f"{42: >+5}"  # Width of 5, align to right, with space as fill and plus or minus as sign
'  +42'
>>> f"{42:#> 5}"  # Width of 5, align to right, with `#` as fill and space or minus as sign.
'## 42'
```

For more info, see the [Format Specification Mini-Language](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language).

---

<sup>1</sup> Does not include the type conversion, for example `!s`, `!r` or `!a`.

Comment: "The expression is everything before the colon" - Not quite. Type conversions aren't part of the expression, either, for example `f'{ 42 !s :10}'` is an [error](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/v6AoM69EI029WsHESEGxWMHK0KBWXfP/fwA) as well.

Comment: @KellyBundy Thank you. I've added a small footnote, as I don't wish the answer to be too complex.